# Android : Selector throws Resources Not Found Exception

Tags: android

Very basic selector.xml that uses a style.xml for its state changes. See below, any help is appreciated.

**This breaks (throws error):**

```
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item style="@style/button_default"/>  
</selector>
```

**However, this works (setting the drawable directly):**

```
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/button_default"/>  
</selector>
```

**Styles.xml:**

```
<style name="button_default">
    <item name="android:background">@drawable/button_default</item>
</style>
```

Comment: If you set style="button_default", what happens?

Comment: Same outcome unfortunately.